# SwipeRefreshLayout animation freezes onRefresh()

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

when I Swipe to Refresh the animation of SwipeRefreshLayout shows, but it is froze while onRefresh() runs, and only starts to spin when onRefresh() is finished.

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myFAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.myFAB);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
    callCadastroEncoemnda();
    callPackageList();
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
            android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
}
```

onRefresh:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    Update.updateAll(MainActivity.this);
    //Check if the data change
    if (!packages.equals(dao.getPackages())) {
        adapter.updateList(dao.getPackages());
    }
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!

I've put the refresh code on a Runnable: 
(I've changed my refresh too)

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (Update.updateAll(MainActivity.this)) {
                    packages = dao.getPackages(config.getFilter());
                    packagesAux = dao.getPackages(config.getFilter());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            adapter.animateTo(packages);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
         .....
        RVAdapterMain adapter = new RVAdapterMain(packages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ....
    }
    .....
}
```

First of this seems like wrong. Could you please use it in onCreate(). And create the new method add the new data inside your adapter. When you refresh it onRefresh method only notifiyDataSetChanged() with new dataset instead of every time using the new adapter.

Comment: Ok, I will change that, but this is used in OnCreate(), by callPackageList();

But still is not the problem, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have setRefreshing(true) statement in onRefresh() method.
When we drag the Ui downward,  the spinning things starts itself automatically.

You just need to setRefreshing(false) to stop the spinner at the place where your desired result is achieved, but not in onRefresh().

For example, if you are hitting an api, we need to setRefreshing(false) at that point where we get the response from server i.e onPostExecute or similar.

Here is how I use it:

```
/**
 * on Refreshing, fetch trip history again.
 */
@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    fetchTripHistory();

}

@Override
        public void onFailOfResponse(Object... arguments) {

            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            noDataText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        }
    };
```

Comment: I've seen that, I put setRefreshin(true); because it was frozen

Comment: umm.. can you explain more what problem are u facing exactly.

Comment: When I pull down to refresh de animation works great, take the finger from the screen to refresh, the animation goes frozen (don't spin)

When I Remove `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` I realized that it just begins to spin when the OnRefresh function ends